# Connect to MongoDB atlas cluster with mongoengine

Tags: mongodb, flask, pymongo, mongoengine, mongodb-atlas

I have a flask application for which I used mongoengine to create the database. But now, I need to connect with MongoDB Atlas' Cluster, but I only could find how to do it with Pymongo:

```
client = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@<database-name>.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority")
db = client.test
```

I just want some help to connect with this new database.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you are using `flask-mongoengine`, you can connect with a given URI with the following pattern:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.mongoengine import MongoEngine

app = Flask(__name__)

# This would usually come from your config file
DB_URI = "mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@<database-name>.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority"

app.config["MONGODB_HOST"] = DB_URI

db = MongoEngine(app)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

If you are using plain `mongoengine`, you establish the connection simply like this:

```
from mongoengine import connect

DB_URI = "mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@<database-name>.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority"

connect(host=DB_URI)
```

This is actually what gets called behind the scene by `flask-mongoengine`

Comment: Thank you! This helped me, I think I was using connect wrong

Comment: THANK YOU!!!!!  @bagerard I really want to say thanks.  The MONGODB_HOST = MONGO_URI was so simple in the end.

Answer (score 2):

I think the way you are placing the URI is wrong in the place of `<database_name>` you should instead put the name of your cluster such as this:

```
app.config['MONG_DBNAME'] = '<DB_name>'
app.config['MONGO_URI'] = 'mongodb+srv://<name>:<password>@<cluster_name>.net/<DB_name>?retryWrites=true'
```

Answer (score 2):

When using `mongoengine` connecting to [MongoDB Atlas](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/) cluster *regardless* of using `flask-mongoengine` you can use the following function:

```
# Connect to, return database
def db_connect(database):
    db_uri = "mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@<cluster>.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority"
    db = connect(database, host=db_uri)
    return db
```

Where the database variable is a string with the name of the database.